# Using parameter in Quarto book title

Tags: r, parameters, yaml, quarto

I am trying to create a parametrised Quarto book where the title of the book, set in _quarto.yml, changes depending on a parameter "name", but I can't get this to work. I use `r params$name` in the title, but it always prints out the in line code into the title rather than the output.

Here is my _quarto.yml code below:

```
project:
  type: book
  execute-dir: project

book:
  title: "Test title for `r params$name`"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - contact_us.qmd
    
format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo
    fontsize: 16px
    mainfont: Arial

execute:
 echo: false
 warning: false
editor: source
```

And the index.qmd where parameters are set:

```
---
params:
  name: "Test"

engine: knitr
---
 
## Introduction {.unnumbered}

This book is about `r params$name`.
```

[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43nZ9.png)

So `r params$name` prints out the output when used in the qmd file, but not the YAML. It looks like parameters must be set in the YAML of each qmd file, rather than in the Quarto YAML script ([post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72992071/specifying-parameters-in-yml-file-for-quarto)). Could this be the cause of the issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think that you cannot use R expressions in a YAML header using Quarto.

Comment: The explanation can be found [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-expressions-in-quarto-yaml-header/171482/2).

Comment: Ah okay, that's disappointing. Thank you for sharing. Do you know of any solutions to this problem that don't involve using R expressions?

Comment: I would have a go using https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/variables.html#var

Answer (score 1):

Meta parameters worked for me:

`"title: "Reportfor {{< meta params.WhoFName >}} {{< meta params.WhoLName >}}."`