# Quarto - Using Parameters in Report Title

Tags: parameters, quarto

I'm trying to create a Quarto report, which will be parametrized by first and last name.  In use, the report file will be called by an R script/:

The title of the report is defined by:

`title: !expr paste("Report Run Log for", params$WhoFName, params$WhoLName)`

In the Quarto file itself the default parameter values for  WhoFName, WhoLName are defined down in the Yaml:

```
  SourceDir: "..."
  SourceFile: "..."
  LogFile: "..."
  WhoFName: "Fred"
  WhoLName: "Jones"
```

When I run the report by rendering the Quarto file in the menu's render command, I get this message:

> Error: object 'params' not found
> Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) :
> Could not evaluate expression: paste("Run Log for", params$WhoFName, params$WhoLName)
> Calls: .main ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> 
> Execution halted

Note that when I print the parameter values further down, they exist and are correct.
**My theory** is that they simply are not defined at the time when the title tries to access them.  **But...**

When I call the report using this command, I get a similar error message:

```
  input = "scripts/Report_Run.qmd",
  execute_params = list(
    WhoFName = "Paul",
    WhoLName = "Jones"
  )
)
```

I get a similar error:

> Error: object 'params' not found
> Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) :
> Could not evaluate expression: paste("Report Run Log for", params$WhoFName, params$WhoLName)
> Calls: .main ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> 
> Execution halted
> Error in `processx::run(quarto_bin, args, echo = TRUE)`:
> ! System command 'quarto.exe' failed

---

> Exit status: 1 stdout & stderr:

---

When I used this render command on a version of the report without parameter values referenced in the title, the correct parameter values are passed and used.

Does anybody have some ideas here, or a good link?

Sincerely,

Barry DeCicco

Comment: you might want to see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76928867/using-parameter-in-quarto-book-title).

Answer (score 2):

Meta parameters worked for me:

```
"title: "Report for {{< meta params.WhoFName >}} {{< meta params.WhoLName >}}."
```

Answer (score 1):

In R you can include parameters in your title by structuring the YAML as shown.

```
---
format:
  html:
    embed-resources: true
  pdf:
    toc: true
    documentclass: report
params:
  WhoFName: "Bill"
  WhoFName: "Bryson"
  disease: "Asthma"
title: "Report Run Log for `r params$WhoFName`  `r params$WhoLName`"
author: "author name"

---
```

Answer (score 0):

I used once javascript to Modify the title of a title. In addition I wanted to make it a link, which was also possible doing it that way.

In particular you have to look in your javascript code for the DOM containing the title and afterwards you can change it.